# Send Email with different Forms to different Email Addresses

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I have 2 Forms , One for Print and One for Cloud and in each Form i have an input field ,where user should write their email address in input feild and when User Submit button for example In Print Form, it should send an email with users email address (Just inform in input feild) to Print Email address and when user submit button in Cloud Form it should send an email to Cloud Email address.
For example;. if Form = Print send value of Input field in Print Form to Print Email Addresse 
if Form = Cloud send value of Input field in Cloud Form to Cloud Email Address
I can get it just work for One Form for example Print , but i dont know how get this things work for the others Forms like Cloud. Can anyone please point me in right direction! thanks :)

PrintForm HTML Markup:

```
 <form id="PrintForm">
                        <input type="text" id="txtEmail" />

                        <input type="submit"  value="Send" />
                    </form> <br>
```

CloudForm HTML Markup:

```
 <form id="CloudForm">
                        <input type="text" id="txtEmail" />

                        <input type="submit"  value="Send" />
                    </form>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#PrintForm").submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var email = $("#txtEmail").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/xxx/AjaxMethod",
                dataType: 'json',
                data:  {
                email: email,
                },
                success: function (status) {
                    console.log('Send');
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                }
            });

        });


    });
</script><br>
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string email)
        {

            var SubjectOne = "Print";
            var SendToPrint = "Print@Print.com";

            var errorMessage = "";

//BookingViewModel
            Booking book = new Booking { 
            Email = email,
            };


            try
            {
                // Initialize WebMail helper
                WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp";
                WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
                WebMail.UserName = "email@email.com";
                WebMail.Password = "";
                WebMail.From = "email@email.com";
                WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
                WebMail.SmtpUseDefaultCredentials = false;


                // Send email
                WebMail.Send(to: SendToPrint,
                    subject: SubjectOne,
                    body: "email: " + email + "<br>"
                );

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
            }

            return Json(book);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your Controller by adding the parameter named `formType`,

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string email, string formType)
{
     if(formType == "print")
     {
        //Perform print related stuff
     }
     else if(formType == "cloud")
     {
         //Perform cloud related stuff
     }
}
```

And updating your AJAX call with `data: { email, formType: "print"}` for Print form,

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/xxx/AjaxMethod",
            dataType: 'json',
            data:  {
               email: email,
               formType: "print"
            },
            success: function (status) {
                console.log('Send');
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }
        });
```

`data: { email, formType: "cloud"}` for Cloud form,

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/xxx/AjaxMethod",
            dataType: 'json',
            data:  {
               email: email,
               formType: "cloud"
            },
            success: function (status) {
                console.log('Send');
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Should i  also do something with my HTML Markup ?!

Comment: Yes, some of thing need to be taken care like, you need to change your input text ids like txtPrintEmail & txtCloudEmail, you need two ajax call one for print and other for cloud to calling controller methods with formType param.

Comment: Just Last Question :) :) what about my email stuff in my controller , would you please give me example with it , beacuse i got problem with return Json

Comment: Actually you forgot to append the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet ex. - return Json(book, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Yes, Thanks Jatin . everything its just work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Register a submit event on the cloud form just like you do for the print form.

```
 $("#CloudForm").submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var email = $("#txtEmail").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/xxx/AjaxMethod",
            dataType: 'json',
            data:  {
            email: email,
            },
            success: function (status) {
                console.log('Send');
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
            }
        });

    });
```

If both the CloudForm and PrintForm are on the same page, you will have to change the `id` of the textbox inputs so that they both have an unique ID.

Comment: but it should send an email to Cloud email addresse ,how should i take care of that?

Comment: Like I said, if both the CloudForm and PrintForm are on the same page you will have to change the id of the textbox inputs.

Fe CloudForm -> txtEmailCloud, PrintForm -> txtEmailPrint

In your javascript you can get the correct email with either 'var email = $("#txtEmailCloud").val();' or 'var email = $("#txtEmailPrint").val();'

Comment: Yes you right ,they both in same page. and with email im mean that email should sending to not that email where user inform in input field , if you see in my contorller i've define get value from input and sendto print email , and this my problem how get Cloud email in play

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the two forms:

```
<form id="PrintForm" id = printFormGroup">

<form id="CloudForm" id = printFormGroup">
```

and then amend your AJAX to respond to the class:

```
$(".printFormGroup").submit(function (e) {
```

This will cover all forms with the same class and will return whatever the user enters.

Comment: It not should send email to whatever email address the user enters, it should take value of input feild and sendto Cloud email address.as you can see in my contoller i define for Print , and its means take value from Print Input feild and than send to Print Email addresse , and i want the same for Cloud ,get value from Cloud Input feild and send value to Cloud Email addresse

Comment: Not Problem , I also update my Question with an example